# How do I start a .launch file from Eclipse IDE

Tags: roslaunch, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I use Eclipse to develop ROS applications and the "cmake eclipse-project" is very helpful for this purpose. But how do I start a .launch file out of this IDE? I made some experiments to define new "External tool configurations" but it does not work :-(

Is there anywhere a guideline or a tutorial for this topic?

Thanks for your help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10043/how-do-i-start-a-.launch-file-from-eclipse-ide/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on 2011-05-24**:
No, I haven't figured out how to use launch files in Eclipse. I activate a launch file for all of the external nodes from the command line and just launch the node I am debugging in Eclipse.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-24**:
I can't answer your question, but perhaps this person can: http://answers.ros.org/question/930/how-to-configure-eclipse-to-properly-load-a-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I take some minutes to find a solution for the problem :

---

Add a new file association for .launch files

1. General -> Editors -> File Association ... add a new file type with the suffix *.launch assign the XML Editor to the new file type
2. General -> Appearance -> Content Types ... roll off entry for TEXT in the menu go to XML and add *.launch

Now a .launch file will be opened by the XML Editor, if you have installed it.

---

In a second step you have to define a new external tool launch.

1. Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations
2. choose PROGRAM and add a new lauch configuration by clicking the left button
3. write a name like “Launch_ROS” to NAME
4. integrate the path of roslaunch into LOCATION (usually something like ../ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/bin/roslaunch)
5. add as ARGUMENTS your ROS package name and .launch file name (for a more general use you can take ${project_name} ${resource_name}, but in this case your focus has to be on your launch file while starting !!!)
6. then you can start the ROS application by Run -> External Tools -> Launch ROS

Anyone feels free to improve the chain !

Best wishes from Germany

Poseidonius

---

Originally posted by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) with karma: 427 on 2011-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-26**:
Nice. I'm sure this well be helpful to many people.

**Comment by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on 2012-09-18**:
I'm trying to run roslaunch or roscore as an External Tool following this guide, but I get an error.
Looks like you probably need to define for eclipse the ROS environment variables, I think I've done so, but then I get this error when running:
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2012-09-18**:
Eclipse looks for a python interpreter in /usr/bin/env/ ... please check this outside Eclipse. Probably you add a wrong path.

**Comment by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on 2012-09-20**:
Outside Eclipse everything works. Could it be that Eclipse overwrites the path to the python interpreter? Maybe because of a default configuration for the PyDev plugin? Do you know which is the variable in Eclipse that defines the path?

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2012-09-21**:
Take a view on Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter Python ... You can use "Auto Config" or declare the path manually.

**Comment by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) on 2012-10-17**:
Thank you, @Poseidonius! This is really helpful.

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-03-02**:
Thanks  @Poseidonius,  I am able to run my launch file in eclipse.  I was wondering is there a way I can debug it as well. That will be debugging in eclipse while running an external tool.

**Comment by [chrisLB](https://answers.ros.org/users/20166/chrislb/) on 2014-12-14**:
I figured out a way of debugging nodes started with a launch config, see my blog post http://www.ceh-photo.de/blog/?p=899

**Comment by [DanielEckert](https://answers.ros.org/users/22166/danieleckert/) on 2015-04-17**:
Just had the following error, but found a solution:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roslaunch", line 34, in 
import roslaunch
ImportError: No module named roslaunch
*Solution:* Eclipse has to be launched from command line to have all environment variables.

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-01-25**:
I'm new with eclipse and was really confused about what should I type in "Working Directory" and "Arguments". Can anyone give me some hints?

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-11-14**:
Thank you for excellent discussion. I have followed tutorial but I am facing a problem. I am getting error as follows

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roslaunch", line 34, in <module> import roslaunch
    ImportError: No module named roslaunch
```

help plz

**Comment by [Nimrods](https://answers.ros.org/users/31954/nimrods/) on 2017-09-19**:
I followed the instructions above and got the following error:
31m[demo_backpack_2d.launch] is neither a launch file in package [cartographer_ros] nor is [cartographer_ros] a launch file name[0m

from the shell it launches fine.

what am i missing?

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-07-09**:
I got the same error @Nimrods. Did you find a solution?